# Custom TitleView in NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am trying to add a a user's image and name to a navigation bar to look like the following:

[image]

I am attempting to do this programmatically, as my codebase doesn't use xibs or storyboards (except for the launch screen).

Here is a brief look at my code:

```
  guard let prof = self.profile else { return }
    let imageView = ImageView(type: .none, avatar: true, 25)
    let nameLabel = UILabel()
    nameLabel.text = prof.name
    nameLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    imageView.setImage(prof.profileImage?.imageURL)
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 300))
    view.addSubview(nameLabel)
    view.addSubview(imageView)
    nameLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(5)
        make.left.right.equalToSuperview()
    }

    imageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.bottom.equalTo(nameLabel.snp.top).offset(5)
        make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(5)
    }
    
    self.navigationItem.titleView = view
```

I use [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit) for laying out the UI and the `ImageView` is just a custom UIImageView that handles downloading images, has a built in loading indicator, some formatting options, and by telling the init that it is an avatar image, requests a much smaller size image too.

I used height of 300 for the parent view only as a test to get the navigation bar taller to accommodate my content, but there was no change in the height.

If anyone has a way to accomplish this design, or an alternative that is similar, I'd very much appreciate the assistance on this.

EDIT: Solutions without the use of SnapKit are totally fine.

EDIT: @asanli's description of a solution results in the following below:

[image]

code is here:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 300))
view.addSubview(nameLabel)
view.addSubview(imageView)
imageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
    make.width.height.equalTo(50)
    make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
}
nameLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.top.equalTo(imageView.snp.bottom).offset(10)
    make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
}
```

Comment: Why don't simply create your own view? UINavigationBar won't have that much space.

Comment: @PGDev Will my own view by in the navigation bar?  The design request and product requirements issued to me is that it needs to be in the navigation bar.  Wouldn't my own view by just below the navigation bar, and hence not the same thing?

Answer (score -1):

I have found one library which may help you. I have never used it but hope it helps you.

https://github.com/Pircate/EachNavigationBar

Comment: I actually tried this exact answer and it doesn't appear that changing the frame works anymore. not for a few iOS versions now at least

Comment: my confusion, is that clearly iMessage is able to do this all just fine

Comment: Oh, Yes you are right I can see, though iMessage behavior seems different while pushing or pressing on back. Though I have found one library which may help you. https://github.com/Pircate/EachNavigationBar  I have never used it but hope it helps you.